# Random long long generator C++

Tags: c++, random, int64

What is a solution to generate random `long long` with cryptographic strength С++? (boost is allowed)

Comment: Why not Boost? -it helps us to understand what your limits are

Comment: @Mark i need a solution without boost because it must work under linux without pre-installed boost libraries

Comment: On linux you can read `sizeof(long long)` bytes from `/dev/random`.

Comment: You can just copy the boost headers for random

Comment: You don't need `boost` on the deployment platform, only on the build machine.

Comment: Thanks, i will create new thread

Comment: @Roman: Why? They are effectively the same quesiton, just combine them. (The answers already do.)

Comment: @GManNickG as i know it is not recommended to change question. I my case from "no boost" to "using boost"

Comment: @Roman: That is a small change in the question that would fit the answers, it's okay. What's not okay is radically changing the question so nothing else (comments/answers) makes sense.

Comment: @GManNickG, ok, thanks, i've fixed thread question

Answer (score 6):

The `<random>` header provides portable access to random number facilities including, potentially, a cryptographic pRNG.

```
#include <random>     // random_device, uniform_int_distribution
#include <algorithm>  // generate_n
#include <iterator>   // ostream_iterator
#include <iostream>   // cout
#include <functional> // bind, ref

int main() {
    std::random_device r;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<long long> dist;

    std::generate_n(std::ostream_iterator<long long>(std::cout, "\n"), 10,
        std::bind(dist,std::ref(r)));
}
```

`std::random_device` may not be a cryptographic pRNG on all implementations, so you'll have to check your implementation documentation. In particular VC++ before 2012 does not provide a non-deterministic implementation. VC++ 2012 and later implements this using Windows cryptography services.

Implementations on other operating systems such as Linux or Mac OS X can commonly use "/dev/urandom" or "/dev/random" or any other random device exposed via the filesystem. E.g. libc++ uses "/dev/urandom" by default, which on OS X uses the Yarrow algorithm.

I know you ruled out boost, but `boost::random_device` has an implementation for Windows that uses that platform's cryptography services.

Comment: +1 for using std but also pointing to boost again (I don't understand why people don't have boost setup by default)

Comment: @gvd: Many companies do not like putting open source code onto the build machine.

Answer (score 3):

Under linux you can read from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`

They both provide cryptographic entropy.

Difference between them being: `/dev/random` blocks if entropy is exhausted, therefore it could be slower than `/dev/urandom` but is "stronger"

So, using streams it will look like this

```
long long n;
std::ifstream rstream ("/dev/random");
rstream >> n;
```